# Who first coined the name "Wahhabi"?

Tags: islam, terminology, etymology

Specifically, did Muslims coin it or non-Muslims?

Is there any evidence, recorded in history, about the first usage of this term?

Comment: As a related matter: http://islam.stackexchange.com/questions/1579/what-is-wahhabism

Answer (score 14):

No one "coined" it; it is a romanization of the genitive form of Muhammad ibn Abd al-Wahhab. The *-i* suffix is the usual way to transliterate it, just as we have Saudi, Kuwaiti, Omani, and so on. (The more common way in English to create a genitive for a thinker would be to use the Greek-derived *-ic* or the Latin-derived *-an*, hence you do see *Wahhabic* and *Wahhabian* like *Platonic* and *Aristotelian*).

Its first use in English is attested in various dictionaries to the first decade of the 19th century.

Answer (score 9):

As an addendum to Choster's answer, Here is [the English usage of "Wahhabi", according to Google's book data](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=Wahhabi%2C+Wahabi%2C+Wahabbi%2C+Wahabby%2C+Wahhabbi&year_start=100&year_end=2012&corpus=0&smoothing=3):

[(Click for larger image)

[image: History of Wahhabi]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5fmC3.png)

Comment: Good graph but be careful of Google book data as there are false positives, for example the [internet](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=internet&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=3) was unlikely to be referred to in the 17th century.  Not to say this is not useful data (**it is**) but care must be taken in how we interpret it.

Comment: @Sardathrion, yes, no large dataset is perfect, but don't discount English either.  "Inter" is a very common prefix, inherited from Latin, (EG: "Interstitial", "Intercept", etc.).  It is possible that early uses were real, but meant something different than the innerwebz.  Maybe: "We caught the fish internet" (between nets). ... ... This is supported by the fact that ["internets" and "inter net" both appear hundreds of years ago](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=internets%2Cinter+net&year_start=1500&year_end=2008&corpus=0&smoothing=0), but are hardly in use today.

Comment: Indeed.  My comment was in no way a criticism of your graph/answer/Google Book.  Just a grain of salt.  ^_~

Comment: @Sardathrion, And I agree with the salt, but I also know that many strange and ¿terrifying? things lurk in the history of the English language.